# How to construct a query that joins records from another table only when multiple relationships are matched between relationship tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I constructed the following tables to showcase my issue:

recipes

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | item1 |
| 2 | item2 |
| 3 | item3 |

users

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | item1 |
| 2 | item2 |
| 3 | item3 |

recipe_classes

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | item1 |
| 2 | item2 |
| 3 | item3 |

recipe_recipe_classes

| recipe_id | recipe_class_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |

user_recipe_classes

| user_id | recipe_class_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |

How do I go about getting rows from recipes only when ->all<- relationships from user_recipe_classes match the relationships in recipe_recipe_classes.

Examples:

1. For record with id 1 from users I should not get back any results
   from recipes (because not all relationships in recipe_recipe_classes
   match those in user_recipe_classes).
2. For records with id 2 from users I should get back records [1,3] from recipes

Comment: So what have you tried? An inner join between the tables should give you what you want, instead of a description can you post the actual desired results based on the data.

Comment: I tried a left join but that didn't get me the desired results. I provided example use cases but perhaps you didn't scroll all the way to the bottom of my question @sTTu

Comment: Yes I did, that's why I suggested instead of a textual description ;-)
Left join is your problem, have you tried inner join.

Comment: No, I am not proficient with SQL. Although I did go into great lengths of trying to get this to work, like I also tried making everything an array and trying to compare arrays in SQL, I failed miserably. Perhaps inner join was what I was missing all along. Thank you for your suggestion I will continue my research

Comment: Can I use inner join to apply the same logic but with ids that I want to feed the query (as an array of integers) - or this is a different approach all together?

Comment: Why don't you post the query you currently have?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following this, should you not get `[1,3]` for the user with an id of 2?

Comment: @RichardHansell you are correct - it was a typo. I updated my original question

Comment: @sTTu My current query will only further complicate things. I am using a different approach where I fetch all preference ids per recipe as an array into a column and I do the filtering process in my backend in javascript code. I need a fresh start approach.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I might understand what you want here? Does this get you started?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE recipe_recipe_classes (
    table_1_id int,
    recipe_class_id int);

INSERT INTO recipe_recipe_classes
VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 3);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE user_recipe_classes (
    user_id int,
    recipe_class_id int);

INSERT INTO user_recipe_classes
VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 3);

WITH summary AS (
    SELECT
        urc.user_id,
        COUNT(rrc.recipe_class_id) AS rrc_count,
        COUNT(urc.recipe_class_id) AS urc_count
    FROM
        user_recipe_classes urc
        LEFT JOIN recipe_recipe_classes rrc
            ON rrc.table_1_id = urc.user_id
            AND rrc.recipe_class_id = urc.recipe_class_id
    GROUP BY
        urc.user_id)
SELECT
    user_id,
    CASE
        WHEN rrc_count = urc_count THEN true
        ELSE false
    END AS good_recipes
FROM
    summary;
    
DROP TABLE recipe_recipe_classes;
DROP TABLE user_recipe_classes;
```

I'm not sure why `table1_id` joins to `user_id`, but this seems to give you what you wanted? Now you would need to find a way to build this into your main query, but the logic would be the same.

How does it work?

I count the number of rows in the `user_recipe_classes` table for each `user_id`, then the number that have a match in the `recipe_recipe_classes` table. If both counts are identical then this `user_id` is okay, otherwise they're not okay.

Comment: Sorry table1_id refers to the recipe table - forgot to switch the name when i was trying to give them a more presentable name rather than table1 table2 etc. Updated my original question

Comment: But I did think of applying some sort of logic like this (and in my research so far I found examples where the count approach was used). Just hoped that there was something more simple. Will try this out and get back to you. Thank you for your effort, much appreciated